# How to create a link/button to allow download for cross-origin image

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to JS. I am currently trying to implement a link/button that will download an image to the user's computer. The image will not be from the same url but a completely different one: for example, some random URL like this [one](https://cdn.akc.org/Marketplace/Breeds/Rottweiler_SERP.jpg). What I tried doing is implementing the button like this:

```
<a href="https://cdn.akc.org/Marketplace/Breeds/Rottweiler_SERP.jpg" download=""</a>
```

But when ever i press the link, I am taken to another page showing the image but the download is not being initiated. Is there any way I can get the image to be downloaded once the user clicks the image/link?

Comment: Your download attribute has no value. What happens if you give it an actual filename there? (This is also not JavaScript, it's just plain HTML.)

Comment: @IceMetalPunk giving the download attribute some value still does not fix the issue. The reason why I added a JS tag since there may be some solution involving JS which can be used ...